# How to Assign a 2D array to a specific position of a 3D array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, slice, assign

I am writing Fortran code by using Parallel Studio. I have 3 2D arrays of the same dimension (A1(20,20), A2(20,20), A3(20,20)). I have also a 3D array B[3, 20 , 20]. I am trying to assign the 2D arrays to specific positions of the B array as described int the following program:

```
Program Main 
implicit none
real, dimension (:, :),     allocatable :: A1, A2, A3
real, dimension (:, :, :),  allocatable :: B
integer:: i, j, k, Array_2d, Rows_2D, Columns_2D 
!---------------------------------------------
Rows_2D    = 20
Columns_2D = 20

!Allocate 2D tables
allocate(A1(Rows_2D,Columns_2D)) 
allocate(A2(Rows_2D,Columns_2D)) 
allocate(A3(Rows_2D,Columns_2D)) 

Array_2d = 3   

!Assign values of 2D tables
Do i = 1,Rows_2D    
Do j = 1, Columns_2D 
A1(i,j)=i ; A2(i,j)=j; A2(i,j)=i+j
End Do
End Do

!Allocate 3D table
allocate(B(Array_2d , Rows_2D, Columns_2D))

B(1,:,:) = A1
B(2,:,:) = A2
B(3,:,:) = A3

End Program Main
```

However when I tried to run the code it hungs forever at the assignement: B(1,:,:) = A1. Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `[]` is not used for Fortran arrays. You must use `()`.

Comment: If the linked question does not solve your problem, you have to be more exact and detailed. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Never say "it seems that does not work". Tell us the exact error message or explain the exact behaviour. Please be specific and detailed. See also [mcve].

Comment: To be pedantic, `[]` is not used for *indexing* Fortran arrays.

Comment: Dear Vliadimir, Thanks for your feedback. I implemented some corrections. At your convinience please check and revert. Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you declaring `B`? At a guess it's not big enough, or is an `allocatable` which isn't allocated. As Vladimir F asks, we ideally need a minimal reproducible example in order to know enough to help. Also, please ask new questions as new Stack Overflow questions rather than editing new questions onto old ones :)

Comment: We really need more details. The actual code  - [mcve]. I do not even understand what *"[it stacks at the first of the above assignement]"* means. Does it just hang forever? Or does it exit the program? Tell us also your compilation command. Try `gfortran -g -fcheck=all`. You can also add `-Wall`.

Comment: Dear both I tried to ammend my previous post. Please check if it is possible.

Comment: This is getting closer to being answerable :) We still need to see how `B` is declared (initially, not just for this subroutine). Also, how do you know that it is the first assignment that causes it to hang?

Comment: (N.B. the point of a minimal reproducible example (MRE) is that we can see the error for ourselves. Any of the ways I can think of to call the subroutine you have given would work completely fine, without an error, so I can't reproduce your error for myself.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know that first statement ceases to hang, because i get to debug the code and when the execution came to this line the program hang. I uploaded my post corrected in a few minutes.

Comment: Actually tse subroutine makes the description of my problem more complicated and i desided to remove it from the question

Comment: Wonderful, that looks like an MRE :) My first thoughts: `A1`, `A2` and `A3` aren't `allocatable`, but you're `allocate`ing them anyway. This should fail to compile. Secondly, do you mean `A3(i,j) = i+j`? Beyond that, I don't see why your program would hang. Does it only hang when you're running it through a debugger?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry i forgot to state that A arrays are allocatable. Yes A3(i,j) = i+j. No it hungs while i run without debugging aw well

Comment: In that case tell us what you do in the debugger, tell us your compiler version (I understand it is Intel) and compiler flags, tell us your operating system version.

Comment: When I compile your code with `gfortran 7.5.0` it runs completely fine. There must be a problem with your setup. We need the information that Vladimir F has asked for in order to help there I'm afraid. (Also, just to check, are you sure that the code you've given gives the error you've described, and that you're not e.g. running old code in its place?)

Comment: Thank you for you support. I use ''Intel Parallel Studio XE Cluster Edition 2020 Update 1'' to debug my code and my operating system is Window 10. #veryreverie I confirm that.